# trigger input in karma/jasmine test in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm trying to test change events in an angular directive I've written, and I've seen documentation where people do things like `input('text').enter('changed value')`, but I keep getting errors `Object doesn't support property or method 'enter'` when I do that.

In my directive, I start off with a regular template which just wraps some text in span. 
If the user clicks on the directive, the span is replaced with an input field where the model is set as the text of the scope (which is retrieved from the text of the initial directive element.

```
directive('criInput', function($compile){
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    template: "<span ng-click=\"edit\" ng-transclude></span>",
    transclude: true,
    link: function(scope, elm){

        elm.bind('click', function(){
            scope.text = elm.text();
            setAsInput();
        });

        function setAsInput(){
            elm.html('<input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-change="updateForm()" />');
            $compile(elm.contents())(scope);
        }

        scope.updateForm = function(){
            console.log('form updated', scope.text);
        }   
    }

}
```

});

and in my test, I have

```
 it('should get the text of a clicked element', inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
    input_field[0].click();
    expect(scope.text).toBe('Terence');
    input_field.find('input').enter('change');
    expect(scope.text).toBe('changed');
}));
```

I am expecting this test to fail, as I am purposefully checking the wrong value at first. 
Can somebody enlighten me on how I should be testing this so that I can confirm that a text field update triggers the updateForm function?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things you should try here.  add the 'edit' event to the scope.  I have to say overall I am very confused as to what your trying to accomplish and there is easier ways than compiling inside the link function when things change.  You lose much of the initial tracking when you replace the contents in this manner.  You could use an ng-show, then just track the clicked to hide/show the span or input respectively.  Good luck.

```
directive('criInput', function($compile) {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            template: '<span ng-click="edit" ng-transclude></span>',
            transclude: true,
            link: function(scope, elm) {

                elm.bind('click', function (event) {
                    scope.edit();
                });

                scope.edit = function() {
                    scope.text = elm.text();
                    console.log('clicked');
                    setAsInput();
                };

                function setAsInput() {
                    elm.html('<input type="text" ng-model="text" ng-change="updateForm()" />');
                    $compile(elm.contents())(scope);
                }

                scope.updateForm = function() {
                    console.log('form updated', scope.text);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

Then modify the testing to do something like this

```
            var initialText = 'Your wrapped text';
            template = '<span cri-input>' + initialText + '</span>';

            var compiled = $compile(template)($scope);
            $rootScope.$apply();
            console.log(compiled[0]);
            var span = compiled.find('span');
            expect(span.scope().text === 'Terence').toBe(false);
            span.length.should.equal(2);
            span.eq(1).click();
            //you have to find the element since you replaced it
            var input = compiled.find('input');
            expect(input.scope().text === initialText).toBe(true);
            console.log('the text ' + input.scope().text);

            $rootScope.$apply();
            console.log(compiled[0]);
```